# How to Set Shipping Cart Price Rule for shipping according to product size

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules

[image]I have to set a shopping cart price rule for shipping where shipping cost can be charges according to product size.
For example, There is a product attribute 'product size' and it has 3 values, heavy, medium,small.
 So i want to set a shipping rule in which Heavy product should be charges $50, medium $30 and Small $15. So how can i create a shopping cart price rule for such condition. and please also tell me about how to set condition for it in shopping cart price rule.

[image]
i have set heavy product has $50.00 fee and medium has a $30.00 fee in different-different rules.But When i go to view the cart it shows $160.00 total. So it should be $80, but its doubling it. Please solve this problem. –
Can anyone solve my problem.............????
Thank you

Comment: but i have to create a shopping cart price rule for this

Comment: yes you can create from cart rule applied to attribute

Comment: Please tell me how can i create, i have no idea about it. please tell me step by step. thank you

Comment: I know the path, but i want to know about condition. please tell me a suitable condition for it.

Comment: admin > promotions > shopping cart price rules > add new rule > conditions > click on + symbol, then click on dropdown > select attribute combination

Comment: If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
Product Size  is  Heavy  
Ship cost  is  50                                                                                                                    i have put this condition but it is not working

Comment: ok good. but after created the rule, you must apply that rules, give the date range and coupon code and clear cache then check

Comment: is there any thing have to do in action tab

Comment: we must fill that all fields, set the discount amount and set all

Comment: but i don't want to set discount amount. i want to set product shipping according to product size, then what i have to do

Comment: set discount method and appy to shipping cost yes.

Comment: is there any need for discount amount if we are setting discount method..??

Comment: yes, for this case, that takes this condition

Comment: The shipping rule not working, i have checked it after clearing cache

Comment: please help me..

Comment: have you filled all information at Rule informations, conditions, actions and lables properly? if possible please post the screenshots, sure i can help you

Comment: Now See the Screenshot and tell me where is the mistake

Comment: yes. i found. enter the value of how much you want to charge extra at discount amount filed in negative. for example, if you want to take  extra 5 rupees, enter -5

Comment: but it is not taking negative value. it shows Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.

Comment: please try it on your magento set up, if it works then tell me the write conditions

Comment: please must give me reply for this.

Comment: is there any solution....??

Comment: hi. please check my answer

Comment: Shopping cart price rules are for discounts not for additions.

Comment: is there any other way to set shipping according to my requirement

Answer (score 1):

I have found module with such functionality. It allows to add extra fee based on Shopping Cart Price Rules without breaking discount functionality.
Module add new total collectors and it handles extra fee to totals.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee

[image: Extra Fee Based on Shopping Cart Price Rule]

Comment: it is working, but there is a problem. when i create a rule for heavy size product, then it works, but when i create a rule for medium size product, and see the cart on front end, the heavy size shipping charges is added in medium size product.

Comment: try to create more rules

Comment: i have set heavy product has  $50.00 fee and medium has a $30.00 fee in different-different rules.But When i go to view the cart it shows $160.00 total.

So it should be $80, but its doubling it. 

Please solve this problem.

Comment: please update your question with updated screenshots. then we can find please

Comment: please see and solve the problem if possible

Comment: in picture there is first product has heavy size so it should be $50 and second one is medium size so it should be $30, but i m not getting $80 as total,it shows double of total 160.

Comment: is there any solution...??